# Как добавить в произвольное поле ACF свои данные?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть в профиле пользователя select с опциями. Опции я получаю с помощью пхп скрипта и мне нужно их воткнуть в select option на ACF. Может кто подскажет скрипт с помощью которого в файле function.php можно воткнуть в профиль пользователя мои данные, которые я могу выбрать в выпадающем списке и сохранить. Много информации перечитал, везде пишут как это сделать на самом сайте, но мне нужно чтоб в поле, которое заполняется в админке

Comment: Если я Вас верно понял, то [должно помочь](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/)

Comment: нет, там вообще ничего нет полезного в этой статье, видел ее раз 200 уже. У меня есть select с пустыми опциями, а надо через скрипт какой-то добавить опции, вот и хз как найти этот скрипт и опции должны быть в админке, которую выбирает администратор а не на страницах сайта

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот пример что я привел в ссылке и есть то что Вам нужно, судя по Вашему же описанию. Если Вы не понимаете что там происходит, это еще ничего не значит. Данный [пример](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/dynamically-populate-a-select-fields-choices/) показывает как в пустое (или не обязательно пустое) поле ACF, добавить свои значения, естественно в админке, естественно это было протестировано. Откуда Вы берете свои опции, это уже другой вопрос, в примере будет просто массив.

```
function acf_load_test_field_choices( $field ) {
    // сброс опций
    $field['choices'] = array();
    // массив Ваших опций. Можно как в примере получать опции из другого поля и тд.
    $choices = ['Test1', 'Test2'];

    foreach( $choices as $choice ) {
        $field['choices'][ $choice ] = $choice;
    }

    return $field;
}

add_filter('acf/load_field/name=testfield', 'acf_load_test_field_choices');
```

Там где `'acf/load_field/name=testfield'` не забудьте поменять на идентификатор Вашего поля. Если возникнут другие вопросы, давайте уточню.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь понял в чем суть. Работает!!!!

Comment: @МаксимБриллиант если действительно работает, можно и галочку прожать) Если нет, то можно уточнить непонятные моменты

Comment: @МаксимБриллиант Если ответ принят, его стоит отметить галочкой внизу. Если информация в ответе полезна, можно нажать на стрелку вверх. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, прожал